# I keep getting TypeError: 'str' object cannot be interpreted as an integer when i try to run my code

Tags: python

I'm almost positive that this is how I should write it but the error keeps coming up, any help? Sorry if the question is messy this is my first time asking. the premise of the program is for each player to draw 5 coins and capture eachothers coins based off of what the other person has
'''

```
from random import randint

def game(army1, army2):
    prisoner1=""
    prisoner2=""
    print ("Player 1:",army1,"\t",prisoner1)
    print ("Player 2:",army2,"\t",prisoner2)
    print ("\n")
    while(len(army1) and len(army2)):
        if(army1[0]=='H' and army2[0]=='T'):
            prisoner1="TH"+prisoner2+prisoner1
            prisoner2=""
            army1=army1[1:]
            army2=army2[1:]
        elif (army1[0]=='T' and army2[0]=='H'):
            prisoner2="TH"+prisoner1+prisoner2
            prisoner1=""
            army1=army1[1:]
            army2=army2[1:]
        else:
            prisoner1+=army1[0]
            prisoner2+=army2[0]
            army1=army1[1:]
            army2=army2[1:]
            if(len(army1)):
                prisoner1+=army1[0]
                army1=army1[1:]
            if(len(army2)):
                prisoner2+=army2[0]
                army2=army2[1:]

        print ("Player 1:",army1,"\t",prisoner1)
        print ("Player 2:",army2,"\t",prisoner2)
        print ("\n")
    if(len(army1) and len(army2)==0):
        print ("Player 1 wins.")
    elif(len(army1)==0 and len(army2)):
        print ("Player 2 wins.")
    else:
        if(prisoner1.count('H')>prisoner2.count('H')):
            print ("Player 1 wins.")
        elif(prisoner1.count('H')<prisoner2.count('H')):
            print ("Player 2 wins.")
        else:
            print ("Tie.")


def createRandom(army):
    opp=""
    for i in range(len(army)):
        opp+="HT"[randint(0,1)]
    return opp

total=input("Enter number of games to be played :")
for i in range(total):
    print ("\nGame :",i+1)
    seq=raw_input("Enter army sequence :")
    # Change below line to :
    # game(seq,createRandom(seq))
    # if you want to randomly generate opposite army
    game(seq[:5],seq[5:])
```

'''

Comment: Where does the error occur?

Comment: I think the issue is that `input` returns a string, but `range` needs and integer. Use `total = int(total)` after the input line and before the loop to convert it.

Answer (score 0):

The Python `range()` function requires an integer value.

But the `input()` function returns a string value and thus `total` refers to a string value.

We need to convert the string to an integer.

This will fix the problem:

```
total = int(input("Enter number of games to be played :"))
```

For more information on the `input()` function, see the Python documentation: https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#input

Specifically:

> The function then reads a line from input, converts it to a string
> (stripping a trailing newline), and returns that.

Comment: Maybe to add a try-statement to test if it's a number would be nicer.

Comment: Thanks so much. I have one more question, on line 57 i get the error NameError: name 'raw_input' is not defined. Which i know is because the raw_input hasnt been given a value yet. What should i use as a value for raw input

Comment: `raw_input()` is not a function that is available in Python 3. It was commonly used/available as an option to get inputs from user in Python 2. I suspect that if you replace that line of code with `seq=input("Enter army sequence :")` you will be able to get another input from your user. Also... if the answer above met your needs to solve the specific problem you referenced in the original question, I humbly ask that you `Accept` the answer.